# Different Methods of Solving Langevin Equation: Inconsistency

Tags: statistical-mechanics, brownian-motion

Consider the Langevin Equation for a Brownian particle, and ignore the inertial term: $$\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}=\mathbf{u}(t)$$ The random kicking velocity can be represented by Gaussian white noise. The aim is to compute the mean square displacement of the particle.

Method 1: Integration yields $$\mathbf{r}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}dt'\mathbf{u}(t')$$ and then square and ensemble average to give $$\langle\mathbf{r}^2\rangle=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{t}dt'dt''\langle\mathbf{u}(t')\cdot\mathbf{u}(t'')\rangle$$ The velocity correlation returns $6D$ (in three dimensions) and thus we obtain $$\langle\mathbf{r}^2\rangle=6Dt$$ as expected.

Method 2: Take a dot product with $\mathbf{r}$ and use the identity $\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{r}^2)=2\mathbf{r}\cdot\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}$ to give $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf{r}^2)=\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{u}(t)$$ Ensemble average to give $$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf{r}^2\rangle=0$$ which returns $$\langle\mathbf{r}^2\rangle=0$$ which is not good.

Can anybody see what the issue is here? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that $ \frac{d}{dt}<r^2> =<\frac{d}{dt}r^2>  $ ?

Comment: @Amara Yes, I think that is fine? I say this because If I do the calculation with the inertial term using method 2, I obtain the correct result (albeit I have to take a limit at the end).

Comment: The problem here is that you're applying the product rule from ordinary calculus to a stochastic differential equation, where it is not valid. If you want to make manipulations like these you will need to learn the machinery of stochastic calculus.

Comment: @MarkMitchison We do not need to go all the way to talking about stochastic calculus.  Most books on statistical mechanics solve this equation without introducing ito calculus . But there other option is that $<r \dot{r}>$ is not equal to zero for all times. Perhaps at t=0 but not for all times. My argument is that since the following is a strict equality$\frac{d r^2}{dt}=1/2 r \dot{r} $ the right side can't have an ensemble average being zero while the left side is non-zero.

Comment: @Amara I don't think I understand your comment. The derivative of $r$ doesn't even exist in the usual sense (it's defined as the "derivative" of a [nowhere differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Some_properties_of_sample_paths)), so I don't think your strict equality can hold here.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I do not disagree with you, we have a wiener process with a non zero quadratic variation for $r$ as opposed to usual continous differentiable function. Never the less if you just google Langevin equation you will see videos of people solving with out ever talking about no where differential functions or ito calculus. So with in this non-rigorous context there must be a simpler mistake. It should be possible to get meaningful and moreover correct results. Albert Einstein understood brownian motion he didn't use stochastic calculus.

Comment: @Amara I agree, OP's method 1 already shows how to solve Langevin equations without stochastic calculus. But the question is about the self-consistency of the underlying mathematics, which in my opinion requires discussing Ito (or avoiding white noise). In fact, this is pretty much the textbook example used to motivate why stochastic calculus is needed to solve these equations. And indeed if one uses the Ito rules the contradiction disappears. However, there may be a simpler route to resolving this problem without stochastic calculus, and if so I would be very interested to see it.

Comment: I think I agree with Mark, the statement that $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf u$ are not correlated is, I understand, tantamount to a choice of regularisation. In which case it better be that the other statements made are consistent with this choice.